# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos^{2n}\pi x$ exists for all $x$ in $\mathbb R$. What is the limit?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I know how to evaluate the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos^{2n}\pi x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\cos\pi x\right)^{2n} = 0$$
for non-integers and $1$ for integers. However, I don't know how to show this limit exists. Do I use the squeeze theorem?

Comment: If you calculate the limit, you also show that it exists...

Comment: So many parentheses mess my brain. Did you mean $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos^{2n}\pi x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\cos\pi x\right)^{2n}\;\;?$$

Comment: yup, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $\;\cos\pi x=\pm 1\iff x\in\Bbb Z\;$, and in this case $\;\cos^{2n}\pi x=1\;$ and we're done.

In any other case, $\;|\cos\pi x|<1\;$. Now, what do you know about $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a^n\;,\;\;\text{for}\;\;|a|<1\;$ ?

Comment: it goes to 0 @Joanpemo

Comment: @boblo There you go: kudos.